# how to create a file to use in asset folder

Tags: android, file, assets

I want to create a .bin file, store it on asset folder and than create the .apk file.
i want to write to that file an array of objects i created.

---

**background:**
right now i have a function that creating the file in the internal files, and the problem with that is that every time somebody will install the application the file will be created differently so i wanted to make it static(the same for every one) by insert it throught the asset folder

---

what is the best way to create the file or solve my problem?

thanks for any help.

---

**Updates:**
the file will be created differently because it has a random constractor. each time i call the constractor with the same parameters ill get different object properties and i cant change that object or the constractor.

Comment: Asset folder is read only.  I would either store it to internal storage or store it on your server.

Comment: `the file will be created differently `, Why?